# Bad Access code 1 with simple NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I am creating a custom object, it is currently very simple.  Below you will find my .h for the object.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface LAZMessagePlayer : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

- (void)play:(UIView*)viewThatWasPressed;
- (void)pause;
- (BOOL)isPlaying;
@end
```

and the corresponding .m for the object

```
#import "LAZMessagePlayer.h"
@implementation LAZMessagePlayer {
    AVAudioPlayer* myPlayer;
    UIView* currentViewPlaying;
}

-(id)init{
    NSLog(@"init audio");
    NSURL* src = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/Developer/Downloads/317.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError* error;
    myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:src error:&error];
}

-(void)play:(UIView*)viewThatWasPressed {
    NSLog(@"play");
    currentViewPlaying = viewThatWasPressed;
    currentViewPlaying.hidden = YES;
    [myPlayer play];
}

-(void)pause {
    NSLog(@"pause");
    currentViewPlaying.hidden = NO;
    [myPlayer pause];
}

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"done");
    currentViewPlaying.hidden = NO;
}

-(BOOL)isPlaying {
    return myPlayer.playing;
}

@end
```

Inside of my ViewController i have declared a private variable at the top of my Controller.m like so,

```
#import "LAZMessagesViewController.h"
@interface LAZMessagesViewController () {
    LAZMessagePlayer* myPlayer;
}
```

Inside my viewDidLoad I alloc/init myPlayer.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationBarExtensionViewDelegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    myPlayer = [[LAZMessagePlayer alloc] init];
}
```

Later inside my Tap handler I receive a BAD ACCESS code = 1 the first time I try to reference myPlayer, here is the first line that breaks

```
if([myPlayer isPlaying])...
```

I am familiar with c++ memory management, but new to Objective-C entirely.  Can somebody please point out my glaringly obvious miss.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. Inside of Object.h I needed:

```
self = [super init];
.
.
.
return self;
```